# Direct installation on VPS running Debian 11

Tags: node.js, nginx, debian, directus

I've installed Directus on my VPS which is running debian 11. The installation was successful, however, when on Login page, I cannot login.

I get "server error encountered"

Has anyone had this problem or can shed a light on how this can be fixed.

the stack:

Debian 11
nginx
maria db
Node

thanks in advance